# Maximum DAE file size for import to SceneKit in IOS application in XCode?

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I have a problem. Some files are converted to .scn and displayed ok. But some files are not. I think that's because of big size (300 Mb) and a lot of polygons. I was looking for an information about maximum file size and maximum polygons count, but find nothing. Does anybody knows where can i get this information ?

Comment: Quick check: is your model correct? Can you see it in Preview, Finder Quicklook, and Xcode? Also check your scaling; I've loaded models where the camera is inside the model, and nothing is visible. Limits are not documented anywhere that I've been able to find, and that's a shame. Please file a documentation bug at https://bugreport.apple.com, and post the number here so we can dupe it. Additionally, you should file a bug with a specific model that doesn't work.

Comment: I see it xcode in designtime in XCODE. So6 I will try to file a bug ...

Comment: do you see any log in the console? SceneKit will probably warn you if your model is too big.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is if the models are being loaded correctly.  Next I would check your camera setup.  If you have multiple cameras in the model, it defaults to the first camera on the list. Are you sure that this camera is set up correctly?  Alternately, you can cycle through all the cameras by double tapping, if you set `scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;`.

The next thing would be to check if the model is too big to load on the target device(s).  It could be memory constrained, it could be fill-rate constrained.  And of course, the limits would differ depending on the device. It varies significantly from a 4S to 6S Plus and iPad 2 to iPad Pro. But here are some things you could try to test the limits:

- Turn on statistics, to see polygon counts.
  `scnView.showsStatistics = YES;`
- In Xcode, in the debug navigator, you can see if you are running out of memory after loading a complex 300MB model + textures.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating new clear scene and copy/paste objects from incorrect file to clear scene. And it's works ...